# Luene 6.2.0 IndexWriter Constructor Not Defined

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to integrate Lucene in my existing project. It works fine if I create a separate project and test Lucene in a separate project. But a problem arises when I add Lucene in some other project. When i try to instantiate IndexWriter object like this:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
```

where:

```
File path = new File("/java-project/index");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(path);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(null);
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
```

I get the following error:

> The constructor IndexWriter is undefined.

P.S I have included all the required jars. I have also tried using previous versions because I thought it to be a compatibility issue but all in vain.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are importing the correct jars?  In 6.2.0, there is no `FSSDirectory.open(File)` method (it takes a `Path`), and your `StandardAnalyzer` call is ambiguous.  It would guess you have some older Lucene jars in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I imported the correct jars as external jars and eclipse places the external jars under 'Referenced Libraries' but I dont know why it did not work. But when I included the same jars as maven dependency it simply worked and yes you are right `FSSDirectory.open(File)` takes `Path` . I reverted the code to the one provided in the documentation. Thanks . I have one more question to ask, can i ask here or do i need to start another thread?